# Detecting X button click of a window in winforms

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

How can I detect the click event of the close (X) button at the top right corner of the control box of a form/window? Please note, I don't want to know about CloseReason, FormClosing, FormClosed or stuffs like these, unless they are inevitable. I exactly 
want to detect if the user clicked the X button of the form. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to? If you make the "Close" menu item from the system menu behave differently from the X button, you will end up confusing people.

Comment: Any reason not to use `FormClosing` and set `e.Cancel = true` in it ?

Comment: Possible reason: form may be closed by other application, therefore user has to be informed that closing by X is not going to help but instead she has to close that application.

Answer (score 8):

If you **really** have a good reason not to use `FormClosing, CloseReason, ...`, you can override the window procedure and write something like this:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A1;
        const int HTCLOSE = 20;

        if (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            switch ((int)m.WParam)
            {
                case HTCLOSE:
                    Trace.WriteLine("Close Button clicked");
                    break;
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

The details can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645620(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old thread, but here is a solution.

To get WM_NCLBUTTONUP work, don't call to base WndProc when you get WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN message :

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A1;
        const int WM_NCLBUTTONUP = 0x00A2;
        const int HTCLOSE = 20;

        if (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            switch ((int)m.WParam)
            {
                case HTCLOSE:
                    // WndProc Form implementation is buggy :
                    // to receive WM_NCLBUTTONUP message,
                    // don't call WndProc.
                    break;
                default:
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONUP)
            {
                switch ((int)m.WParam)
                {
                    case HTCLOSE:
                        Trace.WriteLine("Close Button clicked");
                        Close();    // Optional
                        break;
                }
            }

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A solution is always acceptable, time doesn't really matter unless it's urgent. This is what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: If it's not too much to ask then I would also like to know how the same thing can be detected on the 'System Close Menu' of the window that appears while clicking the top left of the title bar, and while closing the window with ALT+F4 or CTRL+F4 (in case of MDI child)?